# How to Add Records From a Lightning Datatable To a Group

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, dml

I have two Objects PDCN and PDCN Group. I have created a junction Object PDCNJunc also with Master-Detail Relationship to both PDCN and PDCN Group. There is a lightning datatable which shows list of records from PDCN (see attached snapshot).
[image: List of PDCNs]

My requirement is that I want to add selected PDCN's from this list to a particular PDCN Group record such that whenever someone clicks on PDCN group record these PDCN's should be shown. Given below is my code for PDCN list. Any Ideas/Logic are welcome!!

Server Side Controller :-

```
public class PDCNController {
/*
Method Name : getPDCNRecords
Purpose     : To get the wrapper of Columns and Headers
*/
    @AuraEnabled
    public static DataTableResponse getPDCNRecords(String strObjectName, String strFieldSetName){                

        //Get the fields from FieldSet
        Schema.SObjectType SObjectTypeObj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(strObjectName);
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult DescribeSObjectResultObj = SObjectTypeObj.getDescribe();            
        Schema.FieldSet fieldSetObj = DescribeSObjectResultObj.FieldSets.getMap().get(strFieldSetName);

        //To hold the table hearders 
        List<DataTableColumns> lstDataColumns = new List<DataTableColumns>();

        //Field to be queried - fetched from fieldset
        List<String> lstFieldsToQuery = new List<String>();

        //The final wrapper response to return to component
        DataTableResponse response = new DataTableResponse();

        for( Schema.FieldSetMember eachFieldSetMember : fieldSetObj.getFields() ){
            String dataType = String.valueOf(eachFieldSetMember.getType()).toLowerCase();
            //This way we can set the type of a column
            //We do not get the exact type from schema object which matches to lightning:datatable component structure
            if(dataType == 'datetime'){
                dataType = 'date';
            }
            //Create a wrapper instance and store label, fieldname and type.
            DataTableColumns datacolumns = new DataTableColumns( String.valueOf(eachFieldSetMember.getLabel()) , 
                                                                String.valueOf(eachFieldSetMember.getFieldPath()), 
                                                                String.valueOf(eachFieldSetMember.getType()).toLowerCase() );
            lstDataColumns.add(datacolumns);
            lstFieldsToQuery.add(String.valueOf(eachFieldSetMember.getFieldPath()));
        }

        //Form an SOQL to fetch the data - Set the wrapper instance and return as response
        if(! lstDataColumns.isEmpty()){            
            response.lstDataTableColumns = lstDataColumns;
            String query = 'SELECT Id, ' + String.join(lstFieldsToQuery, ',') + ' FROM PDCN__c LIMIT 50';
            System.debug(query);
            response.lstDataTableData = Database.query(query);
        }

        return response;
    }

    //Wrapper class to hold Columns with headers
    public class DataTableColumns {
        @AuraEnabled
        public String label {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled       
        public String fieldName {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String type {get;set;}

        //Create and set three variables label, fieldname and type as required by the lightning:datatable
        public DataTableColumns(String label, String fieldName, String type){
            this.label = label;
            this.fieldName = fieldName;
            this.type = type;            
        }
    }

    //Wrapper calss to hold response - This response is used in the lightning:datatable component
    public class DataTableResponse {
        @AuraEnabled
        public List<DataTableColumns> lstDataTableColumns {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public List<sObject> lstDataTableData {get;set;}                

        public DataTableResponse(){
            lstDataTableColumns = new List<DataTableColumns>();
            lstDataTableData = new List<sObject>();
        }
    }
}
```

Lightning Component :-

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="PDCNController">
    <aura:attribute name="mydata" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <div >
        <div class="slds-m-left_small">  
            <div class="slds-text-heading_large">Create PDCN Group</div></div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12">
        <c:addPDCNGroup/>
    </div>


    <lightning:datatable data="{! v.mydata }" 
                         columns="{! v.mycolumns }" 
                         keyField="Id"/>
</aura:component>
```

Component's Controller :-

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {                       
        helper.getDataHelper(component, event);
    },
})
```

Component's Helper :-

```
({
    getDataHelper : function(component, event) {
        var action = component.get("c.getPDCNRecords");
        //Set the Object parameters and Field Set name
        action.setParams({
            strObjectName : 'PDCN__c',
            strFieldSetName : 'PDCNFieldSet'
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === 'SUCCESS'){
                component.set("v.mycolumns", response.getReturnValue().lstDataTableColumns);
                component.set("v.mydata", response.getReturnValue().lstDataTableData);    
            }else if (state === 'ERROR'){
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " +
                                    errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }else{
                console.log('Something went wrong, Please check with your admin');
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);   
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi there! What problems are you experiencing? What is not working? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I guess There should be a record created on junction object populating the ID fields from Master detail relationships from both masters(PDCN & PDCNGroup). I just don't know how to write apex code for that as creating a record on junction with related object's fields is different i guess.